# C style character using const pointer returns incorrect result

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a local variable’s memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

I've declared a C style array using pointer, and assign it a value returned by a function.

1.`const char* str = chArr->readString();`

Right after above, I want to cout the str as follow:

2.`cout << "pointer to char is = " << str <<endl;`

and the `readString` is:

```
char* CharArray::readString()
{
    std::cout << "Insert a string of max 19 length:" <<std::endl;
    char string[20];
    std::cin.getline(string,20,'\n');
    return string;
}
```

When I put a break point on line 2, I can see the correct result as value of `str`.
But the console window shows nothing, and after passing step 2, when I look at the `str` value, it shows something like "`P÷7`" or "`äû:`",..

Maybe worth saying that for the str I strings with length of 4,5. Not 19 despite the length of str.

Comment: `const char* str` is **not** a const pointer. It's a mutable pointer to const `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. The memory address of this variable is made  available again by the system after the function ends. So it is possible that some other code overwrites it with some random data and that's why you are seeing gibberish.

In order to safely do this, use:

`char* string = new char[20];`

Remember to `delete []` it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks dude, do I need to delete it inside the CharArray's destructor? or where?

Comment: You need to delete the memory when you no longer use it. In this case, it seems to be after the `cout`.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the address of a local variable, the memory for which will be reused by something else after exiting the function. You are far better off returning a std::string instead like this:

```
std::string CharArray::readString()
{
    std::cout << "Type a string and hit enter:" << std::endl;
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    return str;
}
```

This also means that you don't need to worry about the maximum length (at least you don't need to worry at this point, you may have other restrictions you wish to impose elsewhere) and the memory allocations will be managed for you automatically.

Comment: Cheers dude, just was playing around with pointers!

Comment: No problem. It's important to understand them as well as how to manage dynamic memory, but be sure to read up on smart pointers and RAII (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 2):

You create string within the scope of readString. When you return, your string will be destroyed. You have to alloc your string in your function `char *string = new char[20];` if you want to avoid this behavior.

Comment: And free it when you're finished with it.